# Can we claim the vector equation represents a euclidean space?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a vector equation

> $$\overrightarrow{x} = \langle c_1 + 3c_2, 17c_1 + c_2\rangle$$ where $c_1, c_2 \in \mathbb{R}$

Can I say that

> $\overrightarrow{x} = \mathbb{R}^2$

Or I MUST have the vector equation  $x = \langle a, b\rangle$ where $a, b \in R$ but independent of each other?

Comment: Asking whether $\vec x=\mathbb R^2$ does not make much sense. You have vector on one side and set of vectors on the other side of your equality. Did you mean $\vec x\in\mathbb R^2$? Or do you want to aske what are possible values of $\vec x$ (for arbitrary $c_{1,2}$)?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $x=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 3 \\
    17 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    c_1 \\
    c_2 
\end{bmatrix}$ and the fact that columns of matrix are independent so its rangespace is whole of $R^2$